# Calling addEventListener on a element produce a "Not enough arguments" error

Tags: javascript, html

My code works on Chrome but not on Firefox... in Firefox... whenever this piece of code launches..

```
canvas.addEventListener('keydown');
```

I get this error:

```
Not enough arguments
[Break On This Error]   

canvas.addEventListener('keydown');
```

I have `var canvas` near the top as well as this:

```
canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    canvas.width = 512;
    canvas.height = 352;
context = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

I do not know why it works fine on Chrome but not Firefox...

Comment: The second argument to `addEventListener` should be the callback function. See:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener

Comment: Of course that is javascript. The JQuery echivalent is `.on`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a function that executes when the event fires.  It can be specified either inline like this:

```
canvas.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    // your code here to handle the event
});
```

or it can be specified like this:

```
function keyHandler(e) {
    // your code here to handle the event
}

canvas.addEventListener('keydown', keyHandler);
```

Without an event handler function, there is nothing for the event handler to do as no code would execute when the event fires.

Answer (score 11):

The addEventListener function needs a second parameter to specify the function that is called on the event. The real question is why Chrome doesn't generate an error.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use JQuery to bind the keydown event to the canvas.

```
$('#canvas').on("keydown", function(event){
    // code
});
```